# A sequence of nonnegative measurable functions and a nonnegative measurable function satisfy some properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $E = [1,\infty)$.

I have to find a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  of nonnegative measurable functions on $E$ and a nonnegative measurable function $f : E \to [0,\infty)$ which satisfy some properties:

(i) For each $n$, $\int_E f_n < \infty$,

(ii) $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $E$.

(iii) $\int_E f = \infty$.

Here, we define Lebesgue integration of nonnegative measurable functions as in Real Analysis of Royden.

Here are some of my attempt.

First, I consider the function $f = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k} \chi_{[k,k+1)}$ and
$f_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k} \chi_{[k,k+1)}$. They satisfy condition (i) and (iii) but don't satisfy condition (ii).

Second, I consider the function $f_n = \dfrac{1}{n}\chi_{[n,n+1)}$ and $f=0$. It turns out that they satisfy (i) and (ii) but don't satisfy (iii).

Please give me some hint. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not try $f_n(x) = {1 \over x} 1_{[1,n)}$? $\| f-f_n\|_\infty = {1 \over n}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Why not post this as an answer so that the question moves to  the answered questions list?

Comment: @copper. hat wait, you mean f=1/x on E?

Comment: It's effectively a slightly more continuous version of your first attempt, which would also work. (I'm not sure why you think it doesn't satisfy (ii) )

Comment: Yes, $f$ is ${1 \over x}$ on $E$.

Comment: And seconding @BrianMoehring's remark.

Comment: @copper. hat Why $|f(x)-f_n(x)| = \dfrac{1}{n}, x \in E$, I proved that $|f(x)-f_n(x)| \le 1/x$ on $E$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring When I prove $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$, I just only show that $|f_n(x) - f(x) | \le \frac{1}{x}$, which depends on $x$.

Comment: That upper bound isn't actually correct if you're talking about your first attempt.  It would be $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \frac1{x-1}$ or $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}$, but having an upper bound that depends on $x$ doesn't mean the convergence isn't uniform.  You could similarly [fallaciously] say that the upper limit doesn't depend on $n$, so $f_n$ doesn't converge to $f$.  Neither is true in this case.  It just means you haven't found the upper bound you need yet (e.g. $\frac1n$ works).

Comment: @FactorY Draw a picture of $f-f_n$.